# Getting ID from Class when a String has been detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to work out a way so that when a string is detected in a class of html, I can get the specific ID. For example, if the string was "Action", I'd like to detect Action from the following Strings in the class "categoryCont", and then work out which ID that was. At the moment, I'm using a JQuery Method that simply checks if the class contains the text:

```
<button class = "categoryCont" id="1365" onclick="selection = (this.id), setupCategory()">Action and Adventure</button>
 <button class = "categoryCont" id="43040" onclick="selection = (this.id), setupCategory()">Comedies</button>
 <button class = "categoryCont" id="1568" onclick="selection = (this.id), setupCategory()">Sci-Fi and Fantasy</button>
 <button class = "categoryCont" id="43048" onclick="selection = (this.id), setupCategory()">Thrillers</button>
```

The JQuery:

```
if($('.categoryCont:contains(text)'))
```

How can I adapt this code so that it searches each version of the class, and then if it matches the text, it saves the ID for use?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a trigger to initiate this filter? Like an onclick or..?

Comment: Yes, at the moment when I detect a change on user input, it re-runs the method. (I assume that's what you mean? New to JQuery.)

Comment: yep. See kiranvj's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
$(".categoryCont:contains('Comedies')" ).attr('id');
```

This [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kbgfmtrc/)

**Update**

To hide the particular element you can do (no need to find id)

```
$(".categoryCont:contains('Comedies')" ).hide();
```

Still if you want to apply `id` selector do this:

```
var id =  $(".categoryCont:contains('Comedies')" ).attr('id');
$("#" + id).hide();
```

You can also assign the text to a variable.

```
var text = "Comedies";

$(".categoryCont:contains('" + text + "')" ).attr('id');
```

Comment: How would I apply the ID to something? For example, if I wanted to hide each ID that contains the string, how could I use this?

Comment: Last question. That seems to work for static searches, IE "Comedy" but what if I want to pass it a var, for example, '$(".categoryCont:contains(passedString)" ).attr('id');'